# Text encoding problem between NSImage, NSData, and NSXMLDocument

Tags: objective-c, encoding, nsdata, nsxml

I'm attempting to take an NSImage and convert it to a string which I can write in an XML document.

My current attempt looks something like this:

```
[xmlDocument setCharacterEncoding: @"US-ASCII"];

NSData* data = [image TIFFRepresentation];
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

//Put string inside of NSXMLElement, write out NSXMLDocument.
```

Reading back in looks something like this:

```
NSXMLDocument* newXMLDocument = [[NSXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:outError];
//Here's where it fails. I get:
//Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=9 UserInfo=0x100195310 "Line 7: Char 0x0 out of allowed range"
```

I assume I'm missing something basic. What's up with this encoding issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, embedding large amounts of binary data in XML is not a good idea, IMHO.

To answer your question, you need an encoding scheme that supports binary data, such as [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

See this page for more than one way to represent arbitrary NSData as a Base64-encoded string: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

**UPDATE:** The link to Colloquy's NSData additions seems to be broken on that page. Here's the new URL: http://colloquy.info/project/browser/trunk/Additions/NSDataAdditions.m

Comment: Great solution! From totally troubled to fully functional in 11 minutes. :)

Also, yes, this a temporary thing; I'm aware it's ugly.